# Hosting live project on AppHarbour with domain from GoDaddy

Tags: appharbor

I have a domain with GoDaddy and BigRock I want to host with appHarbour. Say I have a domain named "www.someDomain.com" and if some ones comes to this url if should show the application I have deployed on appHarbour.

1. Is this even possible ?
2. If yes, then how ?
3. Also I dont want my url to change

Is hosting live projects with AppHarbour recommended ?

P.S : My web app uses ASP.NET MVC and SQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AppHarbor supports custom hostnames. From [support response](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/44865-hosting-live-project-on-appharbour-with-domain-from-godaddy):

> you'll essentially need to set up a CNAME for www.somedomain.com which point to your app on AppHarbor - for instance using the foo.apphb.com URL. If you're in doubt about how to configure a CNAME for your domain name on GoDaddy I'd recommend reaching out to them.
>
> On the AppHarbor end you'll just need to add www.somedomain.com to your "Hostnames" section

More here:

- http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/44865-hosting-live-project-on-appharbour-with-domain-from-godaddy
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745117/appharbour-application-with-domain-registered-in-godaddy

Comment: Thank @friism, moving to appharbour very soon :D

Comment: can this be done using my 'FREE' appharbour account ?

Comment: @Yasser Custom hostnames are $10/month on AppHarbor: https://appharbor.com/pricing